# Live Search in PHP using AJAX working, but buttons not in td

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, search, livesearch

my live search in working perfectly, but my  tags are not in td. I can't figure out what is the problem. The picture, and the code are below. Thank you in advance.
The problem is down there in td, the the  tags.
[how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVZO5.jpg)

```
enter code here    
<?php

@include('./config/constants.php');
$output = '';

if (isset($_POST['query'])) {
    $search = $_POST['query'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE full_name LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') OR email LIKE  CONCAT('%',?,'%')");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $search, $search);
} else {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM clients");
}
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $output = "<tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Full Name</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
            ";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $output .= "<tr>
                        <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row['full_name'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row['city'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>
                        <td>"
?>
        <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/update-client.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="main-btn">Update Client</a>
        <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/delete-client.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="danger-btn">Delete Client</a>
<?php
        "</td>
                    </tr>";
    }
    echo $output;
} else {
    echo "<h3>No Records found!</h3>";
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that those are the correct array keys inside `$row`? I think you should inspect the `$row` variable and see what it has (EG: `var_dump($row);`). If you turn on PHP Debugging it'll throw a warning if you reference an invalid array key

Comment: You render `<a>` tags immediately because you don't append these links to your `$output` buffer, then you declare a string `</td> ... </tr>` and never use it and only then you render `$output`. My recommendation here is stop injecting HTML into PHP variables and use `ob_start()` & `ob_get_clean()` instead. Your `$output` approach is not really readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're outputting the links before the table rows.
You output them directly and then later output the rows in the variable `$output`.
Remove the `?>` and `<?php` tags in your while loop and have the buttons be part of the `$output` string

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $output .= "<tr>
                    <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['full_name'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['city'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . '<a href="'.SITEURL.'/update-client.php?id='.$row['id'].'" class="main-btn">Update Client</a>'.
                            '<a href="'.SITEURL.'/delete-client.php?id='.$row['id'];.'" class="danger-btn">Delete Client</a>'.
                  ."</td>
                </tr>";
}
```

Comment: If I remove the ?> and <?php tags in my while loop, the problem will be the following: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected identifier "href"

Comment: `and have the buttons be part of the $output string`

Comment: Sorry but I can't figure out the correct syntax to do that, but thank you.